# Hide contacts from search results ,added to specific group

Tags: drupal, groups, search-results

I am looking for hiding contacts in CiviCRM from search results,added to specific group and also Drupal user should be blocked in automatically soon after adding them to a group.Soft delete using civirules is one option.But I don't want the user to get trashed.Any help?

Comment: i think you need to try and explain this a bit more clearly. eg 'blocked' for a user makes sense, but 'thrashed' doesn't. And are you talking about 'drupal users' when you say 'soft delete' as I don't associate that term with Users but I do with Contacts.

Comment: Sorry if I have not clearly explain. Using Civirules, a contact added to a group can be soft deleted so the contact will not be available in quick search results

Comment: Can you edit your question then to be clear where you are talking about Contacts v Users. It helps if you don't use them interchangeably since they mean quite different entities

Comment: i changed 'thrased' to 'trashed'. hopefully that is what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

This is directly not available through UI, but you can do this by creating your own extension and using hooks like post and queryobject.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via UI with [ACLs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#native-civicrm-acls), but it is somewhat messy and does have some performance implications:

- Use the Include / Exclude Search to search for all contacts but your specific group by excluding it and create a smart group for it
- Remove the CMS permission to view / edit all contacts for your desired CMS user role
- Assign an ACL to read / edit your newly created smart group for your desired ACL role
- Assign users to the ACL roles

Perhaps you can play around with the Drupal Rules module and its [CiviCRM integration](https://civicrm.org/blog/lobo/civicrm-integration-with-drupal-rules-module) to block users beeing added to a group.